# How do I download a file from external url to variable?

Tags: javascript

well, getfile can be used to get files from SYSTEM but, how do I download site.com/t.txt ?

I couldnt really find it, and what I found is not useful, please redirect me if asked before.

Comment: How about a GET request with ajax?

Comment: You don't. Javascript has a same origin policy!

Comment: I think you need a server side script for that.

Comment: @adeneo - And it has ways around it, notably CORS.

Comment: @Quentin - more notably JSONP, but you can't just get a random file like site.com/t.txt unless one or the other is supported by site.com

Comment: @adeneo — which is a long way from it not being possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your asking to do is pretty straight forward with in modern browsers with an XMLHTTPRequest. For example:

```
function load(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) callback(xhr.responseText);
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
}
load("site.com/t.txt", function (contents) {
  // contents is now set to the contents of "site.com/t.txt"
});
```

But to ensure complete browser compatibility with Internet Explorer a little more code is required since Internet Explorer uses the ActiveXObject instead of XMLHTTPRequest.

```
function createXHR() {
  if (typeof XMLHTTPRequest === "undefined") {
    if (createXHR._version) return new ActiveXobject(createXHR._version);
    else {
      var versions = [
        "Micrsoft.XMLHTTP",
        "Msxml2.XMLHTTP",
        "Msxml2.XMLHTTP",
        "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0",
        "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0",
        "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0",
        "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"
      ];
      var i = versions.length;
      while (--i) try {
        var v = versions[i], xhr = new ActiveXObject(v);
        createXHR._version = v;
        return xhr;
      } catch {}
    }
  } else return new XMLHTTPRequest();
}
function load(url, callback) {
   var xhr = createXHR();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) callback(xhr.responseText);
   };
   xhr.open("GET", url, true);
}
```

I would really recommend using a library such as jQuery instead of this. For more information

- [XMLHTTPRequest API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [Quirksmode cross browser XMLHTTPRequest](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html)

Comment: Seems that this the XMLHTTPRequest needs to be named XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not working against the Same Origin Policy, this is quite easy. In this case, the domains match if your script is embedded in a page from foo.com and requesting a file foo.com/* and not subdomain.foo.com/*.

You just need to make a GET request with `XMLHttpRequest` for the file and read the file's contents from the response.

If the file is on foo.com but the page isn't, you'll need to host the script on foo.com and then include it in this page with `<script src="foo.com/filerequestscript.js"></script>`. (Of course, if you don't control foo.com, that's not likely to happen.)

Comment: You can't get `.txt` files using script elements, and you can get files across domains with XHR if you use CORS.