# Download a file from URL with different file name

Tags: javascript

I have below functionality using **JavaScript**

The back end gives me a URL to download a file from like below -

```
https://something.org/FILENAME.ZIP
```

So I file name is fixed as **FILENAME.ZIP**

But while downloading a file , the file should get downloaded with custom file name like  **CUSTOMFILENAME.ZIP** instead of **FILENAME.ZIP**

So,

1)The file should get downloaded from URL :  `https://something.org/FILENAME.ZIP`

2)But it should get saved with different file name as : 
**CUSTOMFILENAME.ZIP**

3)I have tried below programme from url - [how to download a file from url using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487199/how-to-download-a-file-from-url-using-javascript-or-jquery)

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = url;
var fileName = CUSTOMFILENAME;
a.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
a.remove();
```

But still file gets downloaded with **whatever file name mentioned in URL**

Can anybody please help me here ?

The file should get saved with **CUSTOMFILENAME** I provide and not **fileName specified** as **part of URL**

Comment: This is usually done on the server side with the [content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header.

Comment: You might have encounter this problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working) You may need to do in 2 steps to workaround it: download the content then write the content to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this see if it works,

```
const documentName = "CustomFileName"; // here your file name 

fetch("http://yourdomain.com")
.then(res => {
    return res.blob();
})
.then(blob => {
    const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = documentName;
    a.href = href;
    a.click();
    a.href = "";
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are giving a object as download name give a string